# Padronizar planilhas no open office

Tags: microsoft-excel, planilha, libreoffice

Tenho um arquivo do open office planilhas com 27 planilhas dentro.
Todas as planilhas são iguais, 3 colunas, titulo, nada de mais.

Preciso de uma forma para formatar todas as planilhas de 1 só vez.
- largura da linha
- cor do cabeçalhos
- largura das colunas

E possível fazer isso de uma só vez no excell ou open office?

Comment: Tentou com macro? se elas são iguais o processo de uma é o mesmo para o restante. Dessa forma acredito que a pergunta fique on topic já que tem algo de programação.

Comment: @rray acho que openoffice não aceita macro.

Comment: @Articuno tem sim, algumas coisas não compativeis com MS office também depende da versão do OO ou se é libreoffice, broffice etc.

Comment: Perguntei aqui pois achei que teria algum macro que poderia ser feito, por isso perguntei nos tópicos de programação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução encontrada foi criar um macro que padroniza as colunas.

```
sub DailyProfit

dim largura as integer
largura = 700

rem define variables
dim document as object
dim dispatcher as object
dim rows1 as integer
dim rows2 as integer
dim rows3 as integer
dim count as integer
dim countColumn as integer

document = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

oCalcDoc = ThisComponent
 oSheets = oCalcDoc.getSheets()
 count = 1
  for each RowIndex in oCalcDoc.getSheets()
    if count = 1 then
        rows1 = RowIndex.getColumns.getByIndex(0).Width
        rows2 = RowIndex.getColumns.getByIndex(1).Width
        rows3 = RowIndex.getColumns.getByIndex(2).Width
      end if

   RowIndex.getColumns.getByIndex(0).Width = rows1
    RowIndex.getColumns.getByIndex(1).Width = rows2
    RowIndex.getColumns.getByIndex(2).Width = rows3

   countColumn = 0
    for each ColumnIndex in RowIndex.getRows
        countColumn = countColumn + 1
        ColumnIndex.height = largura
        if countColumn >= 100 then
            exit for
        end if
    next

   count = count + 1
  next RowIndex

end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Entendi que tens um arquivo com 27 planilhas (abas), se sim, bastar selecionar todas as abas e efetuar a alteração na primeira visível, as demais assumiram as formatações aplicadas. Para separa-las, basta clicar em qualquer aba sem ser a primeira.

Siga este procedimento: Se as abas forem todas em sequencia > Clique na 1a aba, aperte Shift + última aba desejada. // Se as abas não forem em sequencia > Clique na 1a aba, aperte Ctrl + abas desejadas.  Em seguida faça as formatações desejadas na aba ativa (qualquer coisa que fizer será replicada em todas as selecionadas), ao término clique em qualquer outra aba para separa-las. (Realizado em Win7 + LibO 5.3.5.2)

Comment: Ola @Virgilio Novic, não entendi seu comentário, explicar....Isto responde a pergunta sim, para o LibreOffice.

Comment: Tentei isso no libreOffice e ele nao fez, a unica forma que resolveu foi o macro.

Comment: Editei a resposta, siga os procedimentos....